# Web registration in CiviCRM

Tags: webform-civicrm, registration

I have a solution for non-profit organizations here in Sweden and looking for a solution regarding registration of members (persons) on the organisation's website.

On the organisations webpage there shall be a registration page connected to CiviCRM.
When the new person has filled in their information they shall have a response mail.

I want the following information from the new person.

- First name
- Surname
- Street
- Zip code
- Town
- E-mail

And if I can get the following information I will be glad:

- Mobile phone
- Birth date

Do anybody have a solution for this and in what economic level are we talking about?

Comment: Hi Mikael - you'll find a better solution if you can provide some more information about your setup e.g. which CMS are you using and what version of civiCRM? Is this a real 'membership' organization or are you just talking about contacts signing up for a newsletter? CiviCRM can do what you have specified so far 'out of the box', with configuration. Check this link: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/membership/online-membership-sign-up/ and this link: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/profiles/

Answer (score 3):

This is easy to achieve if your website is built using Wordpress, Drupal or Joomla, as CiviCRM integrates with all three of these content management systems.

Having installed CiviCRM (https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installation+and+Upgrades) setting up a 'profile' (a CiviCRM term for a group of fields) is pretty straightforward - lots of guidance on this in the documentation (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/) you can then present this to users as a form on your website for a straightforward sign-up form. I don't think a simple profile form like this allows you to send an acknowledgement email to the user though.

If you are offering a membership CiviCRM has great support for this, with a full-blown membership management component supporting both free and paid-for membership schemes. The membership sign-up mechanism does support sending an acknowledgement email, and you can do much more besides, using the Scheduled Reminder mechanism.

With Drupal as your CMS you can integrate with CiviCRM to enable you to use Drupal's Webform module, giving you more control over forms on your site.

If you are not using one of these content management systems for your website then you would need to integrate using the API.